# Phaser game audio can not play in webview android 4.2

Tags: phaser-framework

Sound can play when a user initiates a touch/click event.

I want sound to auto-play and loop in webview.

And if have 3 audio files I cannot play all.

Comment: What do you have for code currently?

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason that audio doesn't play in browser is by using mp3 format. Make sure you use .ogg format for audio instead of .mp3.